# Como colocar uma imagem dentro do SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Eae Pessoal, estou tendo uma dificuldade, estou querendo colocar uma imagem dentro do meu svg mas não consigo, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Segue meu código:

```
<svg version="1.0"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="988.000000pt"
        height="570.000000pt"
         viewBox="0 0 988.000000 570.000000"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
         id="{{ pillar }}">
          <defs>
            <pattern id="imgPillar02" x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1">
                <image width="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKm5N.jpg"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
            <g transform="translate(0.000000,570.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
            fill="url(#imgPillar02)">
            <path d="M856 4834 l-859 -862 209 -224 c114 -122 285 -304 379 -403 277 -293
            319 -338 357 -385 20 -25 85 -94 144 -155 93 -96 257 -271 923 -985 79 -85
            226 -243 325 -350 100 -107 246 -265 326 -350 80 -86 194 -209 255 -275 60
            -66 150 -163 200 -215 50 -52 136 -144 190 -204 55 -61 123 -133 150 -162 28
            -28 67 -71 88 -95 20 -24 62 -72 94 -107 l56 -62 3094 0 3093 0 0 2850 0 2850
            -4082 -1 -4083 -2 -859 -863z"/ stroke="red" stroke-width="20" fill="url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKm5N.jpg)">
            </g>
        </svg>
```

Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara SVG é algo que domino pouco, mas esse modelo deve te ajudar. De qq forma sua tag do `path` estava errada, tinha uma `/` no meio do código. E o `fill` que vc usou no `path` é desnecessário já que vc colocou o `fill` no `<g>`. Para entender melhor pq usar o fill no  ou não olhe esse exemplo do @GuilhermeNascimento https://codepen.io/brcontainer/pen/PoYXoeE

Mas independente disso, para funcionar tive que refazer o `path` e o resultado ficou assim.

```html
<svg width="988" height="570" viewbox="0 0 988 570" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern0" height="1" width="1">
            <image height="100%" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKm5N.jpg"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0.724889 189.049L228.8 0.5H987.5V569.5H350.703L0.724889 189.049Z" fill="url(#pattern0)" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caro Hugo, o fill pode sim ir no `<g>`, tanto que se existir mais de um elemento no grupo eles herdarão o "fill", o que facilita muito (se for a intenção) adicionar o mesmo fill em diversos elementos, exemplo: https://codepen.io/brcontainer/pen/PoYXoeE

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bem interessante! Não imaginava que funcionaria dessa forma! Vou corrigir na resposta :)

Comment: Pode copiar o exemplo inteiro para o stacksnippet se desejar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento está lá, valeu a dica . Só não descobri ainda pq não consegui fazer a imagem renderizar no path/g do código dele e tive que refazer o path para funcionar :/

Comment: Ainda não olhei o código dele, vou ver com calma, se for algo simples eu comento pra ti e vc edita a resposta adicionando detalhes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento nada, ai vc posta a resposta uai, sei que vc vai ter muito mais para acrescentar :D SVG ainda é meio obscuro para mim. Queria um livro em pt de preferencia para estudar isso

Comment: Já descobri, foi o que eu suspeitava, a área que equivale ao fill dele são apenas "linhas", a parte do meio dele é "vazada", por isto não vai funcionar no código dele, ou seja o contorno na verdade é a area e o meio não tem nada, problema no path dele mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é isso mesmo, pela quantidade de pontos do vetor já da para ter uma ideia, e como o stocke de 20 era para ter ficado bem mais grossa a linha tb. Mas o estranho é que se vc botar um fill de cor sólida tipo `fill="green"` o svg dele fica assim com preenchimento... http://prntscr.com/p926rc

Comment: Aaah entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda de vocês , funcionou :)

Comment: Caro Hugo, realmente não é nas extremidades, o problemas é como os pontos estão "ligados", parece que existe mais de um path, mas na verdade é como eles estão interligados, como se mudassem de direção (totalmente ao contrario) a caba ponta, parecendo até uma "dobradura", veja o resultado com o mesmo path dele: https://codepen.io/brcontainer/pen/oNvJZmd